# k-path for phonon band structure

Tags: phonons, k-points, phonopy, vaspkit

I have observed in research papers that the k-path chosen for electronic band structure and for phonon band structure to be different. I am currently using VASPKIT in order to obtain the path for electronic calculation. But how do I obtain the one for phonon.

I think they should be same, but why do some articles use different path. I plan on using phonopy for the calculation of the phonon bands.

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I agree there is no reason why the two paths should be different.

Answer (score 1):

The question was:

> "but why do some articles use different path"

However, no article was provided that uses a different path. ProfM [said](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9478/k-path-for-phonon-band-structure#comment20512_9478):

> "I agree there is no reason why the two paths should be different."

If someone would like to write a better answer, this one can be flagged for deletion.